# "to reside at the fringes of something/somebody" meaning

Tags: word-meaning

What does "to reside at the fringes of something/somebody" mean in the following sentences and in general?

> While Schlafly and Klayman reside at the fringes of the American
>   far-right, conservative radio host Rush Limbaugh has a much larger
>    following.
>
> Because of their divergence from typical linguistic patterns and
>   formulae, pidgin and creole languages often reside at the fringes of
>   linguistic study.

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of *reside* and *fringe* in a dictionary? *Reside* is being used in a metaphorical sense in this instance.

Comment: I must upvote Mick's comment and downvote this question. You've asked 350 questions here, yet this breaks nearly every guideline in our [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) meta post. You don't tell us where you found these sentences, you don't show any research effort, and you don't explain what you already know and why you are still confused. If you follow the links in an answer to that meta question, you can find [Yoichi's "What does this mean?" model question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74773). More effort, please.

Comment: Oops.Sorry. I could not figure out how to give two different references for two sentences. That would be nice if you show me.Thank you

Comment: Where did you find them? You certainly didn't write them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally "reside" means to "live in a place" (He resides in New York, I reside in a house). The fringe is the outer, or marginal part of an area (from the idea of a fringe being decorative loose threads around the edge of a piece of cloth)

Metaphorically "residing on the fringe" means to be on the edges of a group. Schlafly is less mainstream than Limbaugh, and is probably is more extreme.

Mainstream linguistics studies languages like English, which have an established grammar and vocabulary. The study of pidgins is less common, less central, and hence "on the fringe"

The metaphorical use of fringe is quite common. We use "on the fringe", and as an adjective "A fringe activity" or "a fringe opinion". "The Fringe" is a comedy festival in Edinburgh each year, which happens at the same time as the mainstream Edinburgh Arts Festival.

Comment: Thank you. I understood. Does telling " X reside at the fridge of Y" give an impression of there is also a conflict between these two things, X and Y to some extent in some examples?